# Gitlab ssh to ec2 instance connection timeout

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pem

I'm trying to create an ssh connection to ec2 instance using .pem file and Gitlab pipeline. Here is my deploy section in **gitlab-ci.yml** file:

```
"Deploy":
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apk update && apk add openssh
    - echo "$AWS_EC2_KEY" > Main.pem
    - chmod 0400 Main.pem

  script:
    - cat Main.pem
    - echo $AWS_EC2_HOST
    - echo "docker info" | ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i Main.pem ec2-user@$AWS_EC2_HOST
```

And I got an error Operation timed out. I tried to log values from env variable and .pem file to check if everything is OK, and yes, it logs correct values.
I also tried to do the same from my machine, and successfully connected. What can happened to ssh in pipeline?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to add this command to the pipeline: `ssh-keyscan $AWS_EC2_HOST`. It will check if Gitlab is able to reach out to the instance. It shouldn't fail, if the connection is available.

Comment: Thanks for help. Gitlab is not able as I see, `ssh-keyscan` command failed with error ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1.

Comment: It can either mean: you're using a self-hosted Gitlab which does not provide access to public internet resources, or your Ec2 instance is misconfigured so it doesn't accept connection from the public internet. What is your case? Can you connect to the same instance using your computer?

Comment: Yes, I can connect using my computer.

Comment: Thanks again for your advices. I found the reason - it was incorrect AWS security group set up - the inbound rule with type ssh should have 0.0.0.0/0 as Source value.